# Facebook Share not picking up OpenGraph meta tags from Gatsby site

Tags: facebook-opengraph, gatsby

On a Gatsby site I have an SEO component `seo.js` using React Helmet that is called inside a blog template `blog.js`. However Facebook Share does not recognize the opengraph tags. The site is hosted on Gatsby Cloud, not Netlify.

I've searched the webs for answers but can't find anything. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991920/facebook-not-recognizing-some-gatsby-react-helmet-meta-tags-on-netlify) did not pan out. It does not appear to be caching and re-scraping does nothing.

Tags appear of course when viewing page source directly. At a total loss here. Other sites with similar setups work fine. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

If anyone has had similar issues, I'd love to hear how they fixed this. Thoughts? Thanks.

*Code and error examples below:*

```js
# seo.js

import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby'

function SEO({ description, lang, meta, title, pageUrl, image, post, children }) {
  const { site } = useStaticQuery(
    graphql`
      query {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
            description
            siteUrl
            author
          }
        }
      }
    `
  )

  const metaDescription = description || site.siteMetadata.description
  const metaTitle = title || site.siteMetadata.title
  const metaUrl = pageUrl || site.siteMetadata.siteUrl

  return (
    <Helmet
      defer={false}
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      defaultTitle={metaTitle}
      titleTemplate={`%s`}
      meta={meta}
    >
      {/* General tags */}
      <title>{metaTitle}</title>
      <meta name="image" content={image} />
      <meta name="description" content={metaDescription} />

      {/* OpenGraph tags */}
      <meta property="og:title" content={metaTitle} />
      <meta property="og:type" content={post ? `article` : `website`} />
      <meta property="og:url" content={metaUrl} />
      <meta property="og:image" content={image} />
      <meta property="og:description" content={metaDescription} />

      {/* Twitter Card tags */}
      <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
      <meta name="twitter:creator" content="{site.siteMetadata.author}" />
      <meta name="twitter:title" content={metaTitle} />
      <meta name="twitter:image" content={image} />
      <meta name="twitter:description" content={metaDescription} />

      {children}
    </Helmet>
  )
}

SEO.defaultProps = {
  lang: `en`,
  meta: [],
  description: ``,
}

SEO.propTypes = {
  description: PropTypes.string,
  lang: PropTypes.string,
  title: PropTypes.string,
}

export default SEO
```

```js
# blogs.js

import React from 'react'
import { graphql, Link } from 'gatsby'
import { Container, Row, Col, useScreenClass, Visible } from 'react-grid-system'

import SEO from '../components/seo'
import Layout from '../components/layout'
import Main from '../components/main'
import BlogList from '../components/insights/blogList'
import Pagination from '../components/pagination'

const Blog = (props) => {
  const {
    seoTitle,
    seoDescription,
    seoHelmet,
  } = props.data.contentfulPage
  const posts = props.data.allContentfulInsightsPage.edges
  const { currentPage } = props.pageContext
  const screenClass = useScreenClass()

  return (
    <Layout>
      <SEO
        title={`${seoTitle} ${currentPage > 1 ?  `- Page ${currentPage}` : `` }`}
        description={seoDescription?.seoDescription ? seoDescription.seoDescription : false}
      >
        {seoHelmet ? seoHelmet.seoHelmet : ''}
      </SEO>
      <Main>
        <h1 className={`headline`}>Blog</h1>
        <BlogList posts={posts} />
        <Pagination context={props.pageContext} />
      </Main>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
  query($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    contentfulPage(slug: {eq: "blog"}) {
      id
      slug
      seoTitle
      seoDescription {
        seoDescription
      }
      seoHelmet {
        seoHelmet
      }
    }
    allContentfulBlogs(
      sort: { fields: [date], order: DESC }
      limit: $limit
      skip: $skip
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          title
          slug
          date
          preview
          text {
            json
          }
          image {
            localFile {
              ...blogThumbnail
            }
          }
          category {
            name
            slug
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`

export default Blog
```

The error on FB Sharing Debugger:

> ⚠️ Warnings That Should Be Fixed
>
> **Inferred Property**
>
> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
>
> **Missing Properties**
>
> The following required properties are missing: og:url, og:type, og:title, og:image, og:description, fb:app_id

Facebook Sharing Debugger scraped URL result:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<style data-href="/styles.13d4056a8a600210f038.css">a,abbr, ... </style>
<meta name="generator" content="Gatsby 2.19.49">
<title data-react-helmet="true"></title>
<link as="font" href=" ... " rel="preload" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style id="jss-server-side"></style>
<style data-styled="" data-styled-version="4.4.1"></style>
<script>window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; ... </script>
<link rel="sitemap" type="application/xml" href="/sitemap.xml">
<link rel="canonical" href=" ... " data-baseprotocol="https:" data-basehost=" ... ">
<link rel="icon" href="/icons/icon-48x48.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.webmanifest">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#3FB6E8">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="48x48" href="/icons/icon-48x48.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/icons/icon-72x72.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="96x96" href="/icons/icon-96x96.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/icon-144x144.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="192x192" href="/icons/icon-192x192.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="256x256" href="/icons/icon-256x256.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="384x384" href="/icons/icon-384x384.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="512x512" href="/icons/icon-512x512.png?v=4b382095dbd38c63f79bce6052737f30">
<link as="script" rel="preload" href="/component---src-templates-insight-js-0b3261c291dd76b6e32d.js">
<link as="script" rel="preload" href="/commons-0606cae2f0bba83915df.js">
<link as="script" rel="preload" href="/app-595ec14f594e84b72fc9.js">
<link as="script" rel="preload" href="/styles-9336dff5557f552f77fc.js">
<link as="script" rel="preload" href="/webpack-runtime-5af2f2a5f9a736a820a9.js">
<link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/insights/key-strategies-for-building-websites-that-capture-and-convert/page-data.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link as="fetch" rel="preload" href="/page-data/app-data.json" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html? ... " height="0" width="0" style="display: none; visibility: hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<div id="___gatsby">
<div style="outline:none" tabindex="-1" id="gatsby-focus-wrapper"></div>
<div id="gatsby-announcer" style="position:absolute;top:0;width:1px;height:1px;padding:0;overflow:hidden;clip:rect(0, 0, 0, 0);white-space:nowrap;border:0" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></div>
</div>
<script id="gatsby-script-loader">/*<![CDATA[*/ ... /*]]>*/</script>
<script id="gatsby-chunk-mapping">/*<![CDATA[*/ ... /*]]>*/</script>
<script src="/webpack-runtime-5af2f2a5f9a736a820a9.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/styles-9336dff5557f552f77fc.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/app-595ec14f594e84b72fc9.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/commons-0606cae2f0bba83915df.js" async=""></script>
<script src="/component---src-templates-insight-js-0b3261c291dd76b6e32d.js" async=""></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit** Here are some other fixes I tried...

- [checked for .htaccess issues](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5471)
- [checked if caching issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53991920/facebook-not-recognizing-some-gatsby-react-helmet-meta-tags-on-netlify)
- [using `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet` by default](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/13956)
- [tried disabling other plugins such as `material-ui`](https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet-react-helmet-not-rendering-server-side~285b13a6-5fbd-405d-8f0a-7594cd212a94)

**Edit 2** from my `package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^13.4.0",
  "@fullpage/react-fullpage": "^0.1.17",
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.9.3",
  "@material-ui/styles": "^4.9.0",
  "@vimeo/player": "^2.10.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
  "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
  "eslint": "^6.8.0",
  "eslint-plugin-graphql": "^3.1.1",
  "gatsby": "^2.18.12",
  "gatsby-background-image": "^0.9.12",
  "gatsby-cli": "^2.9.0",
  "gatsby-image": "^2.2.34",
  "gatsby-plugin-canonical-urls": "^2.1.20",
  "gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager": "^2.1.24",
  "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.31",
  "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^2.1.6",
  "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.1.1",
  "gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts": "^1.0.34",
  "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.2.1",
  "gatsby-plugin-robots-txt": "^1.5.0",
  "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.26",
  "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.3.5",
  "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^2.2.26",
  "gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll": "^1.0.4",
  "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^3.1.16",
  "gatsby-plugin-transition-link": "^1.17.7",
  "gatsby-plugin-typography": "^2.3.20",
  "gatsby-source-contentful": "^2.1.73",
  "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.40",
  "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.7",
  "gh-pages": "^2.2.0",
  "gsap": "^3.0.5",
  "intersection-observer": "^0.7.0",
  "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
  "polished": "^3.4.2",
  "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
  "react": "^16.12.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
  "react-formio": "^4.2.4",
  "react-grid-system": "^6.0.7",
  "react-helmet": "^6.0.0-beta",
  "react-hook-form": "^4.9.6",
  "react-icons": "^3.8.0",
  "react-intersection-observer": "^8.25.2",
  "react-player": "^1.15.2",
  "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
  "react-remove-scroll": "^2.2.0",
  "react-scroll": "^1.7.15",
  "react-scroll-to": "^3.0.0-beta.3",
  "react-scrollmagic": "^2.1.1",
  "react-slick": "^0.25.2",
  "react-typography": "^0.16.19",
  "redux": "^4.0.5",
  "styled-components": "^4.4.1",
  "typography": "^0.16.19",
  "uuid": "^3.4.0"
},
```

Comment: What happens if you add all of the missing properties?

Comment: @ksav perhaps there is a misunderstanding - the missing properties are exactly what I am trying to add via React Helmet in `seo.js` above. It is those properties that FB scraper does not pick up properly.

Answer (score 3):

We've stumbled upon this issue recently. We've fixed this, please check if:

- You have updated to the latest version of gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
- You are using version 6.0.0-beta or later of react-helmet
- You are importing React Helmet using import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet' rather than the old import Helmet from 'react-helmet'

Comment: Yup @codetisans, I already tried that per [this link](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/#compatibility-with-react-168-useeffect-hook), as you can see in `seo.js` the `import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'` and not shown above, but in my `package.json` file dependencies I have `"gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.2.1",` and `"react-helmet": "^6.0.0-beta",`. Unfortunately that has not helped either.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Gatsby + Netlify (w/ prerendering enabled). This didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: When I run `curl -v -A Twitterbot SITE_URL` - I do see the twitter: and og: tags correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something similar? It seems that your `Helmet` component is closed before setting up your metadata.

```
   <Helmet
      htmlAttributes={{
        lang,
      }}
      title={title}
      titleTemplate={`%s | ${site.siteMetadata.title}`}
      meta={[
        {
          name: `description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:title`,
          content: metaTitle,
        },
        {
          property: `og:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
        {
          property: `og:url`,
          content: metaUrl,
        },
        {
          property: `og:image`,
          content: image,
        },
        {
          property: `og:type`,
          content: post ? `article` : `website`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:card`,
          content: `summary`,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:creator`,
          content: site.siteMetadata.author,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:title`,
          content: title,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:image`,
          content: image,
        },
        {
          name: `twitter:description`,
          content: metaDescription,
        },
      ].concat(meta)}
    />
  )
}
```

Comment: Good question @ferran-buireu and actually that was my initial setup that did not work. I switched to {children} based <meta /> tags based on (1) the recommendation of another SE post, and (2) because I have a similar setup working on another site, so I thought I'd give it a try. No luck regardless which method I use to add meta tags (children vs props)

Answer (score 0):

I think Google and Facebook both have issues with helmet because of the extra property `data-react-helmet` that helmet add, see: https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet/issues/79

to solve this issue you can add this code to your `gatsby-ssr.js`

```js
    const _ = require("lodash");

    // cleanup html before render
    exports.onPreRenderHTML = ({ getHeadComponents, replaceHeadComponents }) => {
      const headComponents = getHeadComponents();
      replaceHeadComponents(omitDeep(headComponents, ["data-react-helmet"]));
    };

    /**
     * remove properties from collection deep
     * @param collection
     * @param excludeKeys
     * @returns {any}
     */
    const omitDeep = (collection, excludeKeys) =>
      _.cloneDeepWith(collection, value => {
        if (value && typeof value === "object") {
          for (const key of excludeKeys) {
            try {
              delete value[key];
            } catch (_) {
              // console.log("ignore", _);
            }
          }
        }
      });
```

Comment: Nice solution but when I implement this I will be having twice og meta elements one set with `data-react-helmet="true"` and another one without this.

Comment: that is strange but I believe this will not cause any issues since Facebook and Google will ignore the one with `react-helmet`

Comment: yes, but duplicate code is not a good idea plus when I shared URLs in WhatsApp or slack I couldn't see meta information of that URL on that message.